# Get current date in cassandra cql select

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

In SQL, I am able to do:

```
select getdate(), getdate() - 7
```

Which returns the current date as well as current date - 7 days. I want to achieve the same in Cassandra CQL. I tried:

```
select dateof(now())
```

But that does not work. It works only on insert and not in select. How can I get the same? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
select dateof(now())
```

On its own, you are correct, that does not work.  But if you have a table that you know only has one row (like `system.local`):

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT dateof(now()) FROM system.local ;

 dateof(now())
--------------------------
 2015-03-26 03:18:39-0500

(1 rows)
```

Unfortunately, Cassandra CQL does not (yet? [CASSANDRA-5505](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5505)) include support for arithmetic operations, let alone date arithmetic.  So subtracting 7 days from that value is something that you would have to do in your application level.

**Edit 20200422**

The newer syntax uses the `toTimestamp()` function instead:

```
aploetz@cqlsh> SELECT toTimestamp(now()) FROM system.local;

 system.totimestamp(system.now())
----------------------------------
  2020-04-22 13:22:04.752000+0000

(1 rows)
```

Both syntaxes work as of 20200422.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. I did the subtraction thing on my application level.

Comment: @Aaron Huh. Apparently there's a direct [Chinese ripoff](http://www.developersite.org/101-191317-cassandra) of StackOverflow (presumably for the sole purpose of serving ads). That or two other people happened to have a perfectly identical Q/A exchange. The things you learn.

Comment: @Aaron On another note, it's been two years. Do you know if this feature has been added to Cassandra?

Comment: @arbitrarystringofletters It seems basic arithmetic on dates, have been added to cassandra 4.0 in [CASSANDRA-11936](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11936)

Comment: What is query beyound cassandra version 2.2.0

Comment: @indrajitnarvekar This same syntax works in my 4.0-SNAPSHOT build.

Answer (score 1):

From these docs: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/dse/docs/developing/inserting/upsert-date.html

You have to use this:
`toDate(now())`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution that will work on any table you have read access to regardless of whether it has one row, many rows, or even none at all:

```
SELECT toTimestamp(now()) AS now, count(*) FROM any_table WHERE partition_key=xyz;
```

The difference here is that the aggregate function `COUNT(*)` guarantees that the result set will always contain exactly one row.

Obviously, replace `any_table` with a table that you have read access to, and the WHERE clause with something that fully-specifies the table partition key. Again, there don't need to be any actual rows matching the specified value(s) for the partition key so any value(s) of the right type can be hard-coded.

**Update**

If the table has many rows, then `count(*)` will take a long time to complete and may even time out, so use this method with caution.

**Aside**

`dateof()` was deprecated in Cassandra 2.2.0-rc2. For later versions you should replace its use with `toTimestamp()`.